# Can Firebase Performance Monitoring be used to monitor individual API call endpoints, or only the entire URL?

Tags: firebase, firebase-performance

I have been using and loving Firebase Performance Monitoring, however, on the Network section of the dashboard it shows our API URL as https://exampleurl.com/v1/*

Instead of /*, is it possible to break it down by the endpoint names?

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do after it's collected enough data about how your clients are calling your APIs.

Comment: I have over 70k observations but it is still showing /*

Comment: You should contact Firebase support an explain what you're expecting to see compared to what you're actually seeing.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/